# Pass Data Through Navigation Controller With Back Button

Tags: view, controller, navigation, back

Example: A Master Detail application with a text view in the Detail controller. What is the best way to pass the text view data back to the Master view when the user presses the back button?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `@property`in the `MasterView` and pass data back when leaving `DetailView`.

Basically, you can have a `@property` in the `MasterView`:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextView *textView;`

and, for instance, if you are using `storyboard` to go back.

`[self performseguewithidentifier:@"MasterView"...]`

Create an instance of `MasterView`

`MasterView *master = [[MasterView alloc] init];`

And pass your `textView`from `DetailView`to the `@property`created in `MasterView`.

`master.textView = detailTextView;`